# PHP: Using fgets() and fscanf() to read them into variables

Tags: php, while-loop, file-handling, fgets

I am new to PHP and I am struggling to see why my code is not working. Can anyone see why this is?? 
For my code, I am trying to read the text file by using a combo of `fgets()` and `fscanf()` and I want to put these into a set of variables. I want to also return false when the file reaches EOF and I want it to read these records in the text editor into variables and echo their outputs.

```
    $fp = fopen ("branches.txt", "r");
    while ($branch = fgets ($fp)) {
        $branch=trim($branch);
        if (filesize('branches.txt') == 0){
           echo "The file is DEFINITELY empty";
        }
        printf("%2d: ");
        if ($branch === FALSE) print ("FALSE\n");
        else print ($branch . "</br>");
    }
    while ($info = fscanf($fp, "%i %lf %lf")) {
       list ($properties, $income, $expenditure) = $info;
       echo $info;
    }
    fclose ($fp);
```

Text Editer: Location/String
      Integer Float Float

i.e isver heat
12 160.0 77.0

Answer (score 0):

Here

> printf("%2d: ");

missing int value.

You've already read the file(`while ($branch = fgets ($fp))`) to the EOF. Now you need reset the pointer before read the file using `while ($info = fscanf($fp, "%i %lf %lf"))`.

```
rewind($fp);
while ($info = fscanf($fp, "%i %lf %lf")) {
.....
```

Check this link for more: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php

Comment: what integer value is missing from the print exactly?

Comment: `printf("%2d: ");` where is your variable  for `%2d`. It should be `printf("%2d: ", some_variable);1` . Isn't it?

Comment: i have already tried that yesterday but it doesnt change the output